# android : show matching items as a list as user types

Tags: android, list, selectable

I have a list of names maintained in my app. Now in an edit text when user start typing a name i will match for that substring among the names and want to show user as a selectable list . It is similar to email suggestions shown by mail applications. I have done the matching part. How can i show the list of matching items . is it a listview ?

Comment: Is a `AutocompleteTextView` what you are looking for? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autocompleteTextView for this scenario. Refer to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html.

Comment: i think yes.. i will test and accept ur answer . Thank you

Comment: @preetha If you think my answer is correct, pls accept it as an answer